# Windows環境でPython3(Anaconda)を起動しようとするとUnicodeDecodeErrorが出ます

Tags: python, anaconda

プログラミング超初心者です。
Anacondaプロンプトでpythonと入力すると以下のエラーが出ます。

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp932' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 1752: illegal multibyte sequence
```

anacondaを使用していたら突然このエラーが出るようになり、再インストールしても変わらなかったので質問させていただきました。聞きなれない単語がほとんどで困っております。よろしくお願いします。

**実行環境**
python   3.7.3
anaconda                  2019.03

Comment: `C:\Users\<ユーザー名>\.python_history` というファイルを削除してみてください。

Comment: PicoSushiさん、ファイルを削除してみたところ、エラーが消えました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: さん、 無事問題が解決したようでなによりです。回答としてまとめ直したため、解決としてマーク（✓ボタン）をお願いします。

Comment: @PicoSushi 質問とは直接関係ないのですが、コメント欄での「@記法」は一定のルールで省略される場合があります。 - 参考: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2993/3060

Comment: おっと、知りませんでした。先程のコメント冒頭の「さん、」はご推察の通り「@ ojyaru さん」を意図していましたが、消えているのに気付きませんでしたため、補足ありがとうございます。

Comment: @PicoSushi お返事が遅くなってしまって申し訳ありません。stack over flowを使うのが初めてで、システムが把握できてないのですが、解決マークはこれで押せているのでしょうか？また丁寧に回答をまとめ直していただいて大変ありがたいです。

Comment: これで大丈夫です！承認ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pythonのヒストリファイルが破損していたのが原因のようです。同様の質問が本家SOにありました。

[Python unicode error on command line startup - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52049887/python-unicode-error-on-command-line-startup)

同様のエラーについて調べていたところAnacondaでのみ発生するようですので、もしかしたらAnacondaに原因があるのかもしれませんが、とりあえず回答としては以下のようになります。

- `C:\Users\<ユーザー名>\.python_history` を削除する。

  - もしバックアップを取りたい場合、テキストエディタでファイルの内容を確認、必要に応じてコピーなどしておく。